# set different IP address for Vms in bridge mode in Virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ip, bridge

I set up 3 Vms in Virtualbox all in bridge mode.
guests can ping the host but they have the same IP addresses, so how can I change it? ( how can I ping one VM from another VM)
note: I create Vms with clone command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you clone a VM, you get an exact copy. So all IP settings will be copied as well. You will need to edit the network settings in the clones and assign new IP addresses.

If you are using DHCP, assigning a new (unique) MAC address to the network interface of each virtual machine will help.